# Window Open doesn't work in Userscript (using Violentmonkey)

Tags: javascript, userscripts, window.open

Here's a minimal reproducible example of what I'm talking about

```js
OpenInBrowser = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="https://WebsiteName/something"]')[0].getAttribute('href')
window.open(OpenInBrowser)
```

It doesn't open a new window with the link, the script just continues

It works in the browser console though.

This works in the browser console though. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure popups aren't blocked? Anyway, if you want to open a webpage you should probably use the [`GM_openInTab`](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/gm/#gm_openintab) method. Don't forget to `@grant GM_openInTab` in your userscript [metadata](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/metadata-block/#grant)

Comment: What's the difference between window.open and GM_openInTab?

Comment: @OrangeSolution `GM_openInTab` is an api method provided by ViolentMonkey which relies on the [WebExtension api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create) to open the new tab. This is helpful because it doesn't have the same restrictions as the "normal" [web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Glad it worked out for you

Answer (score -1):

Just like @justinw had said, after allowing popups everything works perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).